# How do you summon a Zombie with enchanted armor?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I asked a question earlier "How do I spawn a Zombie with Armor", After about a week of trying to summon a zombie with enchanted armor on my own, I turn to you guys to help me.

I have tried `/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",ench:[{id:34,lvl:1}]},CustomNameVisible:1,CustomName:"Lv.1 Zombie"}`

The command block output Error says "Data tag parsing failed: Unbalanced curly brackets {}"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the closing square bracket (`]`) for your equipment tag.  Try using this instead:

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",ench:[{id:34,lvl:1}]}],CustomNameVisible:1,CustomName:"Lv.1 Zombie"}
```

That just corrects the syntax error.  To get the zombie to wear the armour, you need to fill the hand, feet, and leg slots first:

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",ench:[{id:34,lvl:1}]}],CustomNameVisible:1,CustomName:"Lv.1 Zombie"}
```

But that still doesn't solve everything, because the enchant isn't working.  This is because the `ench` tag is part of the `tag` tag, which is a subtag of item. Use this instead:

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",tag:{ench:[{id:34,lvl:1}]}}],CustomNameVisible:1,CustomName:"Lv.1 Zombie"}
```

Comment: For some reason he is holding the Leather Tunic instead of wearing it. any input?

Comment: I think you need to specify the slot in the equipment tag.  The first entry in the equipment tag is for the item being held, the second for the feet, third for legs, and fourth for the chest.  Therefore, you need three empty tags within the Equipment tag.

Comment: But I was just correcting your syntax error, I don't know for sure how those tags work.

Comment: Not that this answer isn't helpful, but it needs to be updated with an actual answer to the question "How do I summon a Zombie with enchanted armor?" Otherwerwise, future Googlers will find this to be a dead end.

Comment: @Rainbolt: Happy?

Comment: @MBraedley I'm not particularly emotional about this.

Answer (score -1):

I use this for any complex commands:
http://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/
You can use it for all sorts of stuff, Villager trades, custom armour spawners. It even does book generation (not that that's part of the question)